# How to get keyboard state in a Mac OS command line C program?

Tags: c, macos

I want the program to continuously output data, meanwhile detects keyboard state and do responces, without blocking the loop. I think I saw something like this on Windows. Is there anything similar on Mac OS?

Comment: What do you mean by "do responses"?